# spin rotate an image by jquery without using css

Tags: jquery, css, css-transitions

there are some problems that i don't want to use css3 rotate code which is :
`transform: rotateY(360deg)`
instead i want to know is there any other solution to rotate an image in Y-axis using jquery ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#image').animate({
        rotateY: "+=" + (Math.PI)
    }, 500);
```

You will need the transform js plugin found at JSFiddle site [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/kSR9H/2/)

hope this helps

Comment: how can i make this animation constantly?